# maintaining pair of elemts using own class template

Tags: c++

I made my own class template to maintain pair of elements of any type of objects. Now I am going to use this template for another own class MyPoint. this contain 3D cordinates of a point. I think I need to modify this further as my final objective is to use this `PairInfor<MyPoint>` as a `vector<PairInfor<MyPoint> >` and again `vector<vector<PairInfor<MyPoint> > >`. SO, I need your support to modify this as I do not have very knowledge to prepare this types of templates.

I got assistant from some other classes and books, but i need to include most common functions to this. Can anyone help please?

Here is my template class;

```
// class to accomadate two values
//-------------------------------

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>    

template <class Type>
class PairInfor {

private:
        /// two elements of the pair
    Type x[2];


public:
    // Default constructor.
    PairInfor() { x[0] = x[1] = -1; }

    // other Constructors.
    PairInfor(Type xv, Type yv) {
        x[0] = xv; x[1] = yv;
    }

    PairInfor(const Type *v) { x[0] = v[0]; x[1] = v[1]; }  


    //constructor for Coping
    PairInfor(const PairInfor &v) { x[0] = v.x[0]; x[1] = v.x[1]; }

    // Destructor.
    ~PairInfor() {}

        // assignament
        PairInfor& operator=(const PairInfor &v)
          { x[0] = v.x[0]; x[1] = v.x[1]; 
            return *this;
          }


    // Element access, for getting.
    Type V1() const { return x[0]; }


    // Element access, for getting.
    Type V2() const { return x[1]; }


    // Element access, for getting.
    Type operator[] (int i) const { return x[i]; }



    // Element access, for writing.
    Type &V1() { return x[0]; }


    // Element access, for writing.
    Type &V2() { return x[1]; }


    // Element access, for writing.
    Type &operator[] (int i) { return x[i]; }


    // Return a constant reference to the pair
    const class PairInfor &infor() const { return *this; }

    // Return a reference to the pair
    PairInfor &infor() { return *this; }

    // comparing two pair packets
    friend bool operator == (const PairInfor &v1, const PairInfor &v2) 
    { 
         return v1.x[0] == v2.x[0] && v1.x[1] == v2.x[1]; 
    } 

};
```

When I use this template class, I get the following error too.

```
\include\PairInfor.hpp In constructor `PairInfor<Type>::PairInfor() [with Type = MyPoint]': 
\myprogf.cpp   instantiated from here 
\include\PairInfor.hpp invalid conversion from `int' to `char*' 
\include\PairInfor.hpp   initializing argument 1 of `MyPoint::MyPoint(char*)' 
\Makefile.win [Build Error]  [myprogf.o] Error 1
```

How do I solve this error. Is the error with my default constructor in PairInfor. How do I solve this please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: ... and your specific problem is?

Comment: @Georg Fritzsche: want to add missing common functions to be able to use as a common vector<> class. for example clear(), and so on..

Comment: Have you tried it? What doesn't work?

Comment: @Georg Fritzsche: i think in this template i dont have a way to use Pairinfor<mypoint>.clear()...or can i use this or how can i add this function to the template?

Comment: @Georg Fritzsche: i am getting some other error and added to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line doesn't work for any type:

```
PairInfor() { x[0] = x[1] = -1; }
```

You are trying to assign an integer, but `Type` may not support that. `MyPoint` doesn't, hence the error.
You should default-initialize your members:

```
PairInfor() : x() {}
```

Note that `std::pair` might cover your needs already.

Comment: ok. thank you. can i make different constructors. example for integer and double all other types. if i can, i think it is more efficient i guess. then, does the relevant constructor is automatically taken by the compiler? any modification on this please. thanks.

Comment: @user: Yes, you can provide multiple constructors - you already did so for `PairInfor` (default & copy ctor and one for `Type*`). The compiler will choose the best match.